# How can I programmatically load a custom material from Reality Composer Pro?

Tags: swift, realitykit, reality-composer

I have created a custom shader material in Reality Composer Pro (RCP). I can attach it to models in RCP without a problem, but my issue is that I am creating my models in code. I can not figure out how to reference the material in my RCP project.

I'm trying this but getting no luck. I suspect the "Package" string could be incorrect, but the docs don't make it very clear what the string should actually be.

```
if let puzzleMaterial = try? ShaderGraphMaterial.load(named: "MyCustomMaterial", from: "Package", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
    // Do something with the material
} else {
    // No luck
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am sensing that you need to create an Entity via `Entity(named: "MyEntity", in: realityKitContentBundle)` and then somehow get the material component? I haven't found the right recipe yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is best practice or not but I made a copy of
the `PuzzleMaterial.usda` file created by Reality Composer Pro and
added it to the app's main bundle. Then I just load that into into
a `Data` blob and used `ShaderGraphMaterial`s  [`init(named: from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/shadergraphmaterial/init(named:from:)-9qt59)
initializer. I peaked at the `usda` text file to get the "path"
to the material shader:

```
var puzzleMaterial : ShaderGraphMaterial? = nil
do {
    let materialURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "PuzzleMaterial", 
                                      withExtension: "usda")
    if let materialURL = materialURL {
       let materialData = try Data(contentsOf: materialURL)
       puzzleMaterial = try await 
             ShaderGraphMaterial(named:"/PuzzleMaterial/PuzzleMaterial", 
                                  from: materialData)
    }
} catch {
    print("PuzzleMaterial load failed: \(error)")
}
```

I hope some one comes up with a more canonical answer that uses
the Swift Package that bundles the usda file. This works for now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a material at this time unless it is assigned to a mesh in Reality Composer Pro.

For my project we assigned all "loose" materials to individual cubes in Reality Composer Pro. In Xcode find the cube and make a new Model Component with the mesh you want to assign the material that was on the cube.