# Reality Composer Pro material texture not shown when using .generateText in visionOS RealityView

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, visionos, reality-composer-pro

[image: Problem with texture]

I have created an app for visionOS and opened `Packages/RealityKitContent/package` file in Reality Composer Pro.
I clicked `+` button in top right corner and added `Material Library/Generic/Metal/ScratchedMetallicPaint` material to the default sphere.
I can see the metal texture in bottom right corner.

I then use the material in my code as following everytime user selects new material in a picker `Picker`. After picking material `newValue` has value of `ScratchedMetallicPaint`

```swift
 var dynamicMateriala = try await ShaderGraphMaterial(named: "/Root/\(newValue)",
                           from: "Scene.usda",
                           in: realityKitContentBundle)
                            
// setting UV scale parameter did not help 
 try! dynamicMateriala.setParameter(name: "UV_Scale", value:  .simd2Float(SIMD2<Float>(repeating: 20)))
viewModel.dynamicMaterial = dynamicMateriala
```

In RealityView update closure:

```swift
let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 0.07)
let resource: MeshResource = .generateText(message, extrusionDepth: 0.01, font: font)

if viewModel.dynamicMaterial != nil {
        let fontEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: resource, materials: [viewModel.dynamicMaterial!])
 }
```

**Problem:**
ViewModel is ObservableObject and passes material correctly. The problem is that only base **color** of the material is passed and texture is **not** passed from Reality Compose Pro.

I found an answer to similar problem: [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76701584/how-can-i-programmatically-load-a-custom-material-from-reality-composer-pro) but not sure how to to the solution.

I tried the following based on that answer which says we need to assign material to entity in RealityComposerPro first, but not even the first print is logged.

[image]

```swift
 if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Root", in: realityKitContentBundle){
                            
                            print("In Root")
                            if let box = scene.findEntity(named: "Cube") as? ModelEntity {
                                print("In Cube")
                                
                                let materials = box.model?.materials
                                print("In Materials \(materials)")
                              
                            }
                        }
```

Does anybody know what might be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: I solved it by setting higher ```UV_Scale``` in picker
  if (newValue == "ScratchedMetallicPaint"){
                  
                                try! dynamicMateriala.setParameter(name: "UV_Scale", value: .simd2Float(SIMD2<Float>(repeating: 1)))
viewModel.dynamicMaterial = dynamicMateriala
                            }

Comment: Small UV scale was also the problem, but the solution for me was that I had to create cube object in Reality Composer Pro and assign Metal material to it. I could then assign material without any problem to my text. –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Controlling parameters in MaterialX

The problem lies in the incorrect value of the `UV_Scale` parameter - the higher this value (it's `20` in your code), the finer the grain of the material, that is, the more difficult to distinguish its texture (be it car paint or leather). To see texture details, you should decrease the UV scale value (the default is 1.0) rather than increase it.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            var matX = try! await ShaderGraphMaterial(named: "/Root/Leather", 
                                                      from: "Scene.usda",
                                                      in: realityKitContentBundle)
                                 
            try! matX.setParameter(name: "UV_Scale",
                                  value: .simd2Float(.init(x: 0.7, y: 0.7)))
            
            let text = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateText("MaterialX",
                         extrusionDepth: 0,
                                   font: .systemFont(ofSize: 0.5, weight: .black)))

            text.model?.materials = [matX]
            content.add(text)
        }
    }
}
```

For developers:

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77844128/how-to-programatically-set-shadergraphmaterial-properties/77844222#77844222) to find out how to create a controllable input node in RCP.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
This is also important, but the solution for me was that I had to create cube object in Reality Composer Pro and assign Metal material to it. I could then assign material without any problem to my text in code.