# How to programatically set ShaderGraphMaterial properties?

Tags: swift, realitykit, visionos, reality-composer-pro

I have successfully loaded a `ShaderGraphMaterial` object from a Reality Composer Pro `usda` file -- here is a the graph program:

[image]

When I attempt to set a parameter

```
try shotTrailMaterial?.setParameter(name: "TimeDelay.Value", value: .float(1.0))
```

I get a `parameterNameNotFound` exception. What am I missing? What is the trick to defining and/or accessing these shader parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sequence of actions to create MaterialX controlled parameter in ShaderGraph:

- select YourMaterial in RCP left pane
- in Inspector, choose `New Input`
- add Name and correct Type of parameter
- click `Add` (this adds a blue node to the Graph)
- connect this node to any node's input you're going to control
- then in RealityKit, use the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77705497/reality-composer-pro-material-texture-not-shown-when-using-generatetext-in-visi/77705804#77705804)

[image]

Comment: My confusion was that I was trying to make one of my nodes a parameter. I had to deselect all the nodes (by just clicking on the background). Then I could see the "New Input" option in the Inspector.